# How do I make a grouped bar chart from frequency data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a table similar to the following which shows the number of samples which tested positive for viruses within different species:

```
Species Virus   NoTested    NoPositive  Prevalence  LowerCI UpperCI
1   1   100 46  0.46    0.4 0.5
2   1   80  23  0.29    0.2 0.3
3   1   96  3   0.03    0   0.1
1   2   133 45  0.34    0.2 0.5
2   2   23  10  0.43    0.3 0.5
3   2   75  16  0.21    0.1 0.3
1   3   88  24  0.27    0.2 0.3
2   3   94  12  0.13    0.1 0.2
3   3   65  34  0.52    0.4 0.6
```

I want to create a grouped bar graph such that I can show the proportion of positive samples for each species, in sets according to virus. I also want to add error bars showing confidence intervals.

I have tried doing this in ggplot using geom_bar(), but it gives me a really ugly stacked plot.

> bar1<-ggplot(sppPrev3, aes(Species, Prevalence, colour=Virus))

Comment: Can you (1) remove the `>` from your code so we don't have to (2) provide the ggplot code you tried?

Comment: Hi, sorry this is a really stupid question but how should I format it properly without the > ? I'm a newb...

Comment: agstudy took care of it for you.  Can you show the ggplot2 code you were using?

Comment: ok and I think I undid his efforts just now.... Sorry agstudy!!

Comment: @AkosuaHeather you should take the time to read the `markdown editing help`, it is an orange "?"

Comment: @AkosuaHeather in your question you talk about `postive sample` than here you don't even use "NoPositive" variable, and your code don't work (there isn't a geom layer here)...Really asked like that , looks like a homework ...

Comment: @agstudy sorry i just didn't want to post my actual data... as I said I have very little experience with R, or SO ... will put more effort into the question next time, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see: [this link](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/#barcharts) a lot of info about graphing.

also, maybe try using `barplot(t(dataframe), beside = TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry, didn't know AksouaHeather wanted it specifically in ggplot2.